# Is iterating inside a vector slower than accessing indices with a for loop?

Tags: c++

Is iterating through a vector of integers slower than accessing the indices using a loop? Here's what I mean:

```
std::vector<int> nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (int num : nums) {
    std::cout << num;
}

for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
    std::cout << nums[i] << "\n";
}
```

Which one would be faster, which one uses more memory?

I'm just wondering which one is better performance-wise.

Comment: you are iterating a vector of 5 items. Thats almost nothing. printing something one the screen on the other hand takes ages. In any case, if you care about performance you need to measure. There is no other way.

Comment: ***Which one would be faster, which one uses more memory?*** Your compiler may optimize them both to the same code.

Comment: and you should consider that a compiler optimizes your code. Code you write is an abstract description of what the program should do. What your code describes is A) print numbers from 1 till 5 to stdout B) print numbers from 1 till 5 to stdout. What A) and B) does is identical, and a compiler can see that

Comment: how about trying it out. Also look at the code generated by a fully optimzed build, I bet it will be identical

Comment: Im just using this as an example, Im not actually printing anything in my code. I could post the entire thing, but it's pretty big. Nums has a million numbers in it, and it's just running calculations on them, not printing

Comment: how do you expect us to say something about performance of code you do not show us, but instead you show us different code? Details matter.

Comment: You could use `for (const int& num : nums) {` and this one will most likely be no slower than the other.

Comment: For you own real code with millions of elements you probably need to benchmark both solutions with optimization enabled.

Comment: It's very close to certain that there will be no measurable difference between the two styles, as modern C++ compilers are smart enough to generate optimal code for either one.  The main difference is that it's possible to accidentally insert a bug into the latter style (e.g. accidentally entering something like `for int i = 0; i <= nums; i++`) whereas in the former style theres no risk of making a mistake like that.

Comment: optimizing compilers are among the most complicated pieces of software. It is really difficult for humans to predict what a optimizer will do with certainty. There is no reason to believe one version will be much faster or slower than the other, even with lots of iterations and even more so if the loop body is complicated calculations. But at the end of the day, you need to measure

Comment: Those two loops do not do the same thing.

Comment: The first loop does not do `<< "\n"` so it will be a tiny bit faster.

Comment: `i < nums` is an error. You probably meant `i < nums.size()`.

Comment: Here is a [benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/wODWpV_slWrXZpUqAmMMFbEJNrU). The slowest part of the loop will be the call `std::cout::operator <<(int)`

Answer (score 3):

There is ultimately no way to know for sure apart from trying it and measuring it. There are always unexpected things that can happen that can affect the performance, so performance predictions on this level of detail are not always useful. But I would expect that your compiler is smart enough to produce the same code.

There is a chance the first one is slightly faster because it doesn't call `nums.size()` on every iteration. If the compiler can't be sure that `nums.size()` doesn't change, it might actually check the size again, on every iteration. The `:` syntax calculates the start and end of the vector before it runs the loop.

I suppose you meant `i < nums.size()` in the second one.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That benchmark isn't actually measuring anything.  The vectors are empty, and you need to put the `DoNotOptimize(x)` inside the loops to make it do anything.  [Here](https://quick-bench.com/q/W4IDBp1ofrc2DNzthcclQGappGE) is a version that actually does something, and they perform identically.  Strangely, if I move the vector initialization out of the function into a global then [the iterator version is quite a bit faster](https://quick-bench.com/q/7LK9345MlVCqTAXECbwhfuVVypw).  Just goes to show how important it is to benchmark your actual code instead of similar code.

Comment: The [benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/wODWpV_slWrXZpUqAmMMFbEJNrU) I spent hours working on (which had a bug since the beginning) ended up pretty close to yours. I also ran it on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TM5c3vTb1)
The reason why the iterator version IS faster is on line 29 `k0[i]`. That's a call to `std::vector<int>::operator [](size_t)`. The load cannot be optimized because it is clobbered by call (k0 is visible outside the function, `k0[i]` is the 'call').

Comment: In layman's terms "clobbered by call" refers to "dereferencing a pointer to an object that is visible outside the current scope". I recommend [this cppcon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmEsx4MbKoc) to get a better understanding.